# SQL Server with JDBC - Could not find prepared statement with handle X

Tags: sql-server, c3p0, mssql-jdbc

While running an application that accesses SQL Server using the SQL Server JDBC driver (version 4.0) using connection pool backed by C3P0, we are running into a weird error that happens about once a week (with no observable pattern or timing).

The prepared statements execute SQL queries fine, but once a week or so they fail with the following exception:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Could not find prepared statement with handle 2.
>
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
>   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515)
>   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:404)
>   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:350)
>   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
>   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
>   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180)
>   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155)
>   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.execute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:332)
>   at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.execute(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:989)

The version of the Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server (4.0) does not support setting prepared statement caching (or at least that's my understanding reading the [jdbc driver wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/wiki/PreparedStatement-metadata-caching)).

C3P0 is configured with `maxStatementsPerConnection = 50` and `maxStatements = 0` with max connections set to 100.

What should I be looking into to figure out what could be going wrong?

Comment: It happens on a particular statement, or any statement? Also, have you tried with another version of the mssql-jdbc driver (I'm seeing v7.0.0 in releases)? I have no experience in c3p0 but perhaps that has a newer version than what you're using maybe?

Comment: It happens for any statement and that too only occasionally. Unfortunately, upgrading the production servers will require more "proof" that shows that updating the libraries fixes this problem.

Comment: you might try setting `maxStatementsPerConnection = 0` as well, to disable all Statement caching.